# I need to start gdm manually

Tags: boot, 18.04, systemd, gdm

After a difficult update to 18.04 my system is booting into a tty and not into the gnome shell. I found that lightdm was still installed and wanted to start. I deinstalled lightdm and when I do "sudo systemctl start gdm", gnome starts and all is ok. How can I correct this so that my system start normally? Do I need a target for SystemD?

Comment: To which tty (1-6) does the system boot? From which version and how did you upgrade the system (and what was difficult)?

Answer (score 1):

I did "sudo apt install --reinstall gdm" and it was fixed.

Comment: Ran into exactly this problem, reinstalling seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks!